# How to set 2 time intervals for the same function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to know how to set 2 time intervals for the same function?I mean that, now i have set timeinterval of 1 sec to continuously monitor the output of server file.If the output of server file is 0,then color of extension icon changes and it shows a notification.Now the problem is that i have written both these functionalities in the same function.So as i have set time interval for 1 sec and call that function,the notification shows every 1 sec and the color of icon also changes every 1 sec based on server output,which is fine.Now what I need is that i need to change the color every 1 sec.but i need to show notification only every 5 min.can you please help me.i have posted my background.js.can you please help me?
here is my background.js

```
var myNotificationID = null;
var oldChromeVersion = !chrome.runtime;
var interval = 5 * 60 * 1000;   // 5 minutes in milliseconds
 var lastNotification = 0;
setInterval(function() {
 updateIcon();
 }, 1000); 

function getGmailUrl() {
 return "http://calpinemate.com/";
}

function isGmailUrl(url) {
 return url.indexOf(getGmailUrl()) == 0;
}

function onInit() {
 updateIcon();
 if (!oldChromeVersion) { 
  chrome.alarms.create('watchdog',{periodInMinutes:5,delayInMinutes:  0}); 
 }
}

function onAlarm(alarm) {
 if (alarm && alarm.name == 'watchdog') {
  onWatchdog();
 } 
 else {
  updateIcon();
 }

 function onWatchdog() {
  chrome.alarms.get('refresh', function(alarm) {
  if (alarm) {
   console.log('Refresh alarm exists. Yay.');
  } 
  else {
   updateIcon();
  }
 });
}

if (oldChromeVersion) {
 updateIcon(); 
 onInit();
} 
else {
 chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(onInit);
 chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(onAlarm);
}

        function updateIcon(){
   if(localStorage.username){

      var urlPrefix = 'http://www.calpinemate.com/employees/attendanceStatus/';
      var urlSuffix = '/2';

        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

       req.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {

        if (req.readyState == 4) {

        if (req.status == 200) {


       var item=req.responseText;


       if(item==1){

        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"calpine_logged_in.png"});

        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[190, 190, 190, 230]});

        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:""});  

        chrome.notifications.clear('id1', function(){});

         }

      else{

       chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"calpine_not_logged_in.png"});

       chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[190, 190, 190, 230]});

       chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:""}); 
       var now = new Date().getTime();
       if (now - lastNotification > interval) {
       chrome.notifications.create(
       'id1',{
       type: 'basic',
       iconUrl: '/calpine_not_logged_in.png',
       title: 'Warning : Attendance',
        message: 'Please mark your Attendance !',
       buttons: [{ title: 'Mark',
                        iconUrl: '/tick.jpg'
                  },{ title: 'Ignore',
                        iconUrl: '/cross.jpg'}],
       priority: 0},
       function(id) { myNotificationID = id;}
           );    
         }    
       }

      } 
   else {

        alert("ERROR: status code " + req.status);

       }

    }

          });
   var url = urlPrefix + encodeURIComponent(localStorage.username) + urlSuffix;
    req.open("GET", url);


   req.send(null);
    }
   }


 onInit();
```

Comment: how do you know it is not firing twice?

Comment: No i am not asking how to fire it twice.I am just asking how to display icon color change every 1 sec and notification every 5 min

Comment: Your question is `2 time intervals for the same function?`, use setInterval twice.. if your question is different write it

Comment: yeah.exactly.if there is any other way as i want to show,please help me.

Comment: You can use a single function that counts how much time has passed since t0 (zero time), if 1 second passed, call FunctionA, if 60 seconds passed, FunctionB, if 61 seconds FunctionA, etc..

Comment: sorry,i couldn't follow you..can you please explain in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is to keep track of the time when the last notification was displayed and always check if 5 minutes have passed since. E.g.:

```
/* Put these 2 lines at the very top of your script */
var interval = 5 * 60 * 1000;   // 5 minutes in milliseconds
var lastNotification = 0;
```

Then, inside the `updateIcon()` function, replace this line:

```
chrome.notifications.create(...);
```

with these lines:

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
if (now - lastNotification > interval) {
    lastNotification = now;
    chrome.notifications.create(...);
}
```

The above piece of code will make sure the notification is created **only** if 5 minutes have passed since the last time a notification was created. It will also update the `lastNotification` variable with the present time.

Comment: Hey. i tried your code.but it is not working.I have updated my code putting yours in it.but still it is showing every 1 sec.

Comment: I hope your logic is right.but it is not working in my code.please help me

Comment: My logic is very right. This is unbelievable, dude ! At least copy-paste correctly. It will really not be long until nobody will be answering your question if you not change your attitude (not matter how many accounts you create). Try copy-pasting **all** of my code, then try again, then if it does not work try to figure out why (for a change).

Comment: hey please check my code.i have done just as you said.please have a look

Comment: just see what i have done and then blame me.i have done just as you said.now what should i do??

Comment: I **did** check your code, that's why I was so pissed off. The code is there for you to use. Maybe **you** are the one that needs to pay closer attention to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Have this code, which runs functionA every 60 seconds, and in between functionB

```
var launchTime = undefined;

function Launcher() {
 if (undefined  == launchTime) {
  launchTime = new Date();
 }
 nowTime = new Date();
 diff = (nowTime.getTime() - launchTime.getTime()) / 1000;
 if (diff % 60 == 0 and diff > 0) { // 60 seconds have passed
  functionA();
 } else { // 1 second has passed
  functionB();
 }
}

function functionA() {
}
function functionB() {
}
setInterval(function() { Launcher(); }, 1000);
```

Comment: but my function A and B are in the same function.I hope you didn't follow my question.In my code,there is a function named updateIcon().In it,it is reading server file and acts according to it.In that if item==0,2 things are performed.one is to change icon color and other is to show notification.And what i want is that i need to show the notification in every 5 min and need to change icon color in every 1 sec.Presently everything s done in 1 sec.I know that it is becoz,i have set time interval to 1 sec.

Comment: I think you are not reading my code, you are just expecting me to give you an answer, you can use my same method of `diff` to do something every 5*60 seconds, and another every 1 second

Comment: Becoz,as i said both the functionalities are present in the else condition of the same function.please check my code.

Comment: In your case function A and B are different functions.But in my case,function B is inside function A